# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

Tags: compiling, php, zlib

I installed Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 64-bit in VMware.

I am trying to compile PHP 5.4.14 on the machine. Here's the bit where `make` stops due to an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/mysqlnd/.libs/mysqlnd_net.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'uncompress' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I have the same version of php compiled and built on a 12.10 32-bit VM and it seems to be working properly.

I have checked that I have `zlib1g` `zlib1g-dev` and `zlibc` installed. What could be the problem?

Comment: You are compiling vanilla or debian package?

Answer (score 0):

`--with-libdir=lib64` should do the trick. I think you forgot to do a `make clean` after adding the `--with-libdir` configuring and prior to `make compile` .
I've just compiled php version 5.5.2 using `phpfarm` and initially encountered the same issue described by you when using `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd`. Adding `--with-libdir=lib64` AND `make clean` fixed the issue.